# IOS - Set fram image in UITableView using Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using Storyboard and display data in UITableView.
I have a problem with show image in UITableView, i want to show image dynamic frame but it's dosen't work

The first: I have a string

```
NSString * abc = @"Helllo stackoverflow, Im a new bie, Im glad with you.";
```

Second: I'm get Width,Height of NSString "abc"

```
CGSize sizeLabel = [(text ? text : @"") sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(180, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

and the final: I'm set sizeLabel.width, sizeLabel.height into frame image

```
int x = 60;
int y = 30;
image.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,sizeLabel.width,sizeLabel.height);
```

**When I set frame UILabel -> It'r run OK**

```
comCell.lblText.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,sizeLabel.width,sizeLabel.height);
```

Here my full code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSDictionary *dataTable = [_itemsNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *text = [dataTable objectForKey:@"Content"];

    NSString *cell = @"cellCus";
    CustomCell *comCell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cell];

    UIFont *font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    CGSize sizeLabel = [(abc ? abc : @"") sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(180, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trang.png"];

    //Image
    comCell.imgAvatar.image = [img stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:14];
    [comCell.imgAvatar setFrame:CGRectMake(63, 26, sizeLabel.width + 10,sizeLabel.height + 10)];

    return comCellLeft;
}
```

-> Somebody help me, or know why comCell.image.frame display wrong frame.

Thank you for read!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but try this:

```
(...)
//Image
comCell.imgAvatar = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(63, 26, sizeLabel.width + 10,sizeLabel.height + 10);
comCell.imgAvatar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trang.png"];
(...)
```

Let me know if it helped you.